# CakePHP 4 Find Function Override for Table?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

Need such your help to override find function for table and I don't know how . I'm spend lot of day but can't found any of answer .and I'm beginner in this. help me to find out this problem solution . need such of help totally confuse  I need this format in answer-

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Admin] => App\Model\Entity\Admin Object
                (
                    [id] => 39
                    [username] => admin
                    [password] => admin
                    [status] => Y
                    [name] => Admin
                    [[new]] => 
                    [[accessible]] => Array
                        (
                            [username] => 1
                            [password] => 1
                            [status] => 1
                        )

                    [[dirty]] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => 1
                        )

                    [[original]] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [[virtual]] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [[hasErrors]] => 
                    [[errors]] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [[invalid]] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [[repository]] => admin
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Admin] => App\Model\Entity\Admin Object
                (
                    [id] => 58
                    [username] => mbfmbf
                    [password] => mbfmbf
                    [status] => Y
                    [name] => Admin
                    [[new]] => 
                    [[accessible]] => Array
                        (
                            [username] => 1
                            [password] => 1
                            [status] => 1
                        )

                    [[dirty]] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => 1
                        )

                    [[original]] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [[virtual]] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [[hasErrors]] => 
                    [[errors]] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [[invalid]] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [[repository]] => admin
                )

        )

)
```

try to modify vender file but can't get any success. help me to find out this problem
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What query are you using to get your data? How is the data formatted from that compared to what you want? Why do you "need" to have the data formatted this particular way?

Comment: @GregSchmidt it's my CakePhp2 version output but now want in CakePhp 4 in this format . It's requirement in this formation . I want this formation in all find function so try to modify find function override . so can you help me to solved this problem .

Comment: I converted a project a few years ago, and honestly while it was a big pain at the time, changing everything to work with the Cake 4 object-based format was well worth it in the long term. The data structure is much more intuitive to use now. There might be a way to change it, but if so I don't know what it is, and it might be a ton of work to do. If your requirement to format like this is an internal thing, you may be able to make the case to change that requirement?

Comment: So we've finally figured the actual problem, your habits, or possibly your frontend or something that wants this data structure. As @GregSchmidt said, you're much better off going the extra mile and get used to the new, _much_ more sensible data structure, it's definitely worth it. Trying to bring back the 2.x structure is certainly possible, but a huuuuge pain in the butt, not least because it will conflict with all sorts of expectations that the framework makes about data structures.

Comment: @ndm i know it's very hard for me not  for you. hope you don't mind can you provide me live example to how to override custom finder  so i follow these step to solved my problem and it's also helps to other's whose they are new in filed  . thanks  in advance for help it's good to see you that's helping nature to fresher

Comment: +1 to the above, if this is not a short-lived app, you will be much better off if you upgrade to the latest architecture. The (seeming) complexity it imposes pays back in clarity, flexibility and maintainability. Plus, it will inevitably teach you a thing or two on how to write good software. If this is a live app, you can try to run a CakePHP 4 copy next to it while you migrate. You can configure the new models and entities to connect to the old database (particularly if it doesn't follow the conventions).